# Most efficient and clean way to push a value to an array only if it does not exist yet

Tags: javascript, lodash

Suppose an array named `myArray` containing several values but no duplicates.
Suppose I want to push a value into it only if it won't lead to duplicates presence.
How I determinate duplicates => by comparing value's `id`.

I thought about [Lodash#uniq](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq) to do the trick:

```
myArray.push(aNewValue);
myArray = _.uniq(myArray,function(item){
   return item.id;
});
```

However, I don't like the reassignment to the array and especially the fact that I have to push before checking...
Is there a more "functional" way to achieve it while being very short?

I don't want to iterate through the array explicitly in order to apply the check.
That's why I attempted to use Lodash.

Comment: By their very nature, you can't check to see if a value is in an array (without some other supporting parallel data structure) unless some code somewhere loops through the array looking for the value.  That code might be inside another method (like `.indexOf()`), but it's still fundamentally looping through the array.  If you want to actually avoid the brute force search for the value, then you need to use a different data structure (like a map) that lets you directly lookup a value rather than brute force search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is generally to use an object for uniqueness, because an object can have at most one key of a certain value. However, this is restricted to strings and things that stringify, since only strings can be object keys.

There are two approaches here. If you are using your array often, then you should keep parallel structures - an object for uniqueness check, an array for arrayness of it.

If you don't need your array often, i.e. you want to push a bunch of things and then have an array be unique, you can just use the object, and transform it into an array when you need it (which is somewhat expensive, so you only want to do it once, but still cheaper than manipulating two different structures all the time).

The first approach is illustrated here:

```
function Set() {
  this.presence = {};
  this.array = [];
};
Set.prototype.push = function(key, value) {
  if (this.presence[key]) return;
  this.presence[key] = true;
  this.array.push(value);
};

var a = new Set();
a.push(3, { id: 3, value: "SOMETHING" });
a.push(7, { id: 7, value: "SOMETHING ELSE" });
a.push(3, { id: 3, value: "SOMETHING" });
console.log(a.array); // => only 2 elements
```

The second, here:

```
function Set() {
  this.store = {};
};
Set.prototype.push = function(key, value) {
  this.store[key] = value;
};
Set.prototype.array = function() {
  var that = this;
  return Object.keys(this.store).map(function(key) { return that.store[key]; })
};

...
console.log(a.array()); // note the newly added parentheses :)
```

Both of these are still cheaper than looking for presence inside the array using `indexOf`, even more so when you do your own iterating, except very much maybe in case the array is very short.

Comment: First solution implemented :) Unit tested use case and works great

Answer (score 4):

You can check the presence of an item before adding it :

```
if(myArray.indexOf(aNewValue) == -1) {
    myArray.push(aNewValue);
}
```

Comment: This solution makes check using a strict equality over the entire value. I would like to check only for the `id` of each item. It would potentially be more performant.

Comment: If you have something with ids, then use an object, not an array; it will trivially (and quickly!) keep uniqueness.

Comment: @Mik378 - comparing the objects with `===` is going to perform much faster than comparing each `.id`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Really? How could it be possible? Suppose values differ only by the `id` field, and that there are 6000 other properties, how could `===` be more performant?

Comment: @Mik378 - `===` between two JS objects just checks to see if the two are the same physical object (no property comparisons at all).  If that's all you care about, that's simple and very fast.  If you can have different objects with the same id, then you have to compare id's.  Your question does not explain at all what `aNewValue` is so we really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.some()` to find out if the value is already part of the array, e.g.:

```
if( myArray.some(function (elem) { return elem.id == newValue.id }) ) 
   myArray.push(newValue);
```

You can't really get away with not looping through the array, though.